# Convert a relational logical schema model(in oracle) into elasticsearch nosql logical schema less

Tags: oracle10g

Could you please suggest me how to do a schema design(nosql) in elasticsearch.
As per my requirement we have already 'relational logical schema' (which is oracle schema) but we are building new version of software which has chosen ES as a NoSql Solution.
How to start the schema design in ES.
Thanks in advance

Regards,
Jaas

Answer (score 0):

I am new on Elasticsearch and I am not sure if I got your question, but I haven't created a schema on Elasticsearch I just converted my data for json format and indexed it.